# Is my plan for running conduit to a new subpanel sound?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, conduit

I'm installing a new subpanel in my basement that I am finishing and thinking to run some conduit from it out to the garage and down to the crawl space below for flexibility on adding future circuits to the garage and finished basement.

Questions:

1.) In this one going to the crawl space, would I just terminate it into a PVC junction box like this one? Do I need to strap this conduit it all (it's about 44" from floor plate to the subpanel.

[image: crawlspace]

[image: jbox]

2.) Would this conduit mockup I have be ok to run into the garage wall? Then later, use a metal LB and EMT on the finished garage wall side to run up to jboxes, outlet boxes, etc?

Another thought would be to run SER for a subpanel in the garage.

[image: garage]

Comment: Run the sub-panel from wires in the conduit, unless you have a pile of leftover SER.

Comment: @Ecnerwal ok, thx. And do you see any issues with my conduit mock up?

Comment: 1-1/4" ~2" PVC conduit needs a support every 5'. ... 1" PVC it's every 3'. Mock up is fine as long as it doesn't turn *another* 180 before finding a pull box. You get two more 90s or one more 90 and an offset (worth 90) for a total not to exceed 360. - If there's a lot more turns to do and you want less boxes; drill to go straight up and not need an offset there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plan seems fine. I would use a metal box so I can use it as a master ground splice.  That way you only need 1 ground wire.

Run individual THHN wires in the conduit, not cables - you run out of conduit fill space very quickly with cables.

Note multiple circuits in 1 conduit require a thermal derate, this starts to really pinch at 4 or more circuits.  If that's a problem, run #2 aluminum and #8 copper ground to a subpanel.  The sub's lugs are made of aluminum, so might as well take advantage of that. #2Al is good to 90A, so should support your current needs plus dual EV charge stations.